# Uploading multiple files through form from different fields and storing into mongodb databse using express multer

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, multer, multiple-file-upload

[image]I am trying to upload two image files a database called cast using multer .I am taking the images as input from a form. I realized that some times it takes files from all the input fields but sometimes it accepts only one image file as input.
Can anybody please help me?Thank you in advance

adminUpload.ejs

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form class="uploadForm" method="post" action="/admin/postFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Enter the name of the actor</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="actor"><br>
            <label class="control-label">Upload the image of the actor</label><br>
            <input name="uplactor" type="file" class="file"><br>
            <label>Enter the name of the actress</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="actress"><br>
            <label class="control-label">Upload the image of the actress</label><br>
            <input name="uplactress" type="file" class="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

AdminRouter.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const controller=require('../Controller/Admin');
const multerFileUpload=require("../Models/Admin")
router.get('/postFile',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('adminUpload.ejs');
    })
var tempupload=multerFileUpload.upload.fields([
    {name: 'uplactor',maxCount: 1},
    {name: 'uplactress',maxCount: 1}])
router.post("/postFile",tempupload,controller.uploadDB)

module.exports=router;
```

Admin.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
const storage= multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.fieldname === 'uplactor'||file.fieldname === 'uplactress'||file.fieldname === 'director'||file.fieldname === 'uplSideCharacter') {
            // if uploading cast photo
            cb(null, 'public/cast_images')
          }
        else if(file.fieldname === 'uplTrailer'){
            // else uploading trailer 
            cb(null, 'public/trailers')
          }
        else if(file.fieldname === 'uplMovie'){
            // else uploading movie
            cb(null, 'public/movies')
        }
        else if(file.fieldname === 'uplposter'){
            // else uploading poster
            cb(null, 'public/posters')
          }
        cb(null, 'public/posters');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(file.fieldname === 'uplactor'||file.fieldname === 'uplactress'||file.fieldname === 'director'||file.fieldname === 'uplSideCharacter'||file.fieldname === 'uplposter'){
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
        return cb(new Error('You can upload only image files!'));
    }
    else{
    cb(null, true);
    }
    }
    if(file.fieldname === 'uplMovie'||file.fieldname === 'uplTrailer'){
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(mp4|mp3)$/)) {
        return cb(new Error('You can upload only video files!'));
    }
    else{
    cb(null, true);
    }
    }
};
exports.upload = multer({ storage:storage, fileFilter: fileFilter });
```

Admin.js(Controller file)

```
const Cast = require('../Models/Cast');
exports.uploadDB=async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        console.log(req.files)
        console.log(req.files.uplactor[0])
        console.log(req.files.uplactress[0])
    const actor=new Cast({
        name:req.body.actor,
        image:req.files.uplactor[0].filename
    })
    const actress=new Cast({
        name:req.body.actress,
        image:req.files.uplactress[0].filename
    })
    await actor.save();
    await actress.save();
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send("hello");
     }catch(err){
      res.send(err);
     }
}
```

app.js

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const AdminRouter = require('./Routes/AdminRoutes');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app=express()
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => {
  console.log('server running');
});
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/admin',AdminRouter);
//connection to mongodb
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Movie';
const connect = mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser : true, useUnifiedTopology: true  } );
connect.then(() => {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
}, (err) => { console.log(err); });
```

Cast.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CastSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
const Cast = mongoose.model('Cast', CastSchema)
module.exports= Cast
```

Comment: `I realized that some times it takes files from all the input fields but sometimes it accepts only one image file as input` means is there any error or req.files not contain correct files or what?

Comment: @DimplePatel thank you for replying. It means that when I console.log(req.files) in Admin.js(Controller file) sometimes it displays two files as I am taking as input two files in adminUpload.ejs but sometimes it displays only one file

Comment: Have you checked the http request sent from the browser inspector to see if both files are actually sent?

Comment: By the way, you should store the images in `Buffer` format instead of `String`.

Answer (score 2):

I have taken your code and debug it.At my end i have used 4 images(2 of them having size in KB and 2 are 9-10 MB) for testing purpose and found that problem exist when either one or both input file of large size(MBs).
so,in uploadDB method you've created two instance of Cast model and then save it.to solve your problem create one instance save it and then create second instance and save it.

```
const actor = new Cast({
            name: req.body.actor,
            image: req.files.uplactor[0].filename
        });
        await actor.save();
        console.log(req.files.uplactress[0]);

        const actress = new Cast({
            name: req.body.actress,
            image: req.files.uplactress[0].filename
        });
        await actress.save();
```

hope this might help

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsgVP.png)[image: Output]

Comment: Hey,Thank u for replying.I added an image to the question after editing the code as you suggested.I still have the same problem.As you can see uplactress does not have any file

Comment: req.files.uplactress contain other fields once execution of `await actor .save()` will be complete so move `console.log(req.files.uplactress[0])` after `await actor .save()`.and even though as per your image uplactress not having any file but check your folder where image will store it contain your uploaded image and check into database as well it have updated record

Comment: I have attached console output in my answer.please check your database and output folder and let me know if it works or not